# How to import var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler; on ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am switching over to ES6, and I have that concern right now.

`var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;`

I did `import RouteHandler from  'react-router'.RouteHandler`, and webpack is giving me an error.

So, how should I import it ?

Comment: Not familiar with ES6, but couldn't you just import react-router and do sth like `var RouteHandler = router.RouteHandler`?

Comment: @Dodekeract yes, I can just I have it and as I posted in my question `var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;`, but I want to now the ES6 way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `import {RouteHandler} from 'react-router'`

Alternatively, you could have done:

```
import * as reactRouter from 'react-router';
var RouteHandler = reactRouter.RouteHandler;
```

Comment: yes, just tried and it's working :)

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked. Just added an alternative approach as well.